# $\sum (-1)^{n+1} n^{1/n} $ is not converging?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

why is $\sum (-1)^{n+1} n^{1/n}$ is not converging? What is meant by convergence here, is the value does not stay firm?

Comment: Do the terms of the series converge to zero?

Comment: If $n^{1/n} \to 0$ then by the alternating series test this series will actually converge.

Comment: $n^{1/n}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: More simply, $n^{1/n}>1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @CameronJWhitehead No. Check again the alternating series test.

Comment: @Did, yeah missed the word monotonic out there

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IT IS NOT converging as the general term
$$
a_n=(-1)^{n+1}n^{1/n},
$$
DOES NOT converge to zero.

Note. An alternating series, such as the one in the OP, converges provided that the underlying sequence is positive, decreasing and tends to zero.

Comment: [this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29+n%5E%281%2Fn%29+%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity) says inconclusive. And [this mobile link](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29+n%5E%281%2Fn%29%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity) says it doesnot converge.